# R - using regex to delete all strings with 2 characters or less

Tags: r, regex, string

I've got a problem and I'm sure it's super simple to fix, but I've been searching for an answer for about an hour and can't seem to work it out.

I have a character vector with data that looks a bit like this:

```
  [5] "Toronto, ON"                    "Manchester, UK"                    
  [7] "New York City, NY"              "Newark, NJ"             
  [9] "Melbourne"                      "Los Angeles, CA"                         
 [11] "New York, USA"                  "Liverpool, England"            
 [13] "Fort Collins, CO"               "London, UK"                              
 [15] "New York, NY"
```

and basically I'd like to get rid of all character elements that are 2 digits or shorter, so that the data can then look as follows:

```
  [5] "Toronto, "                      "Manchester, "                    
  [7] "New York City, "                "Newark, "             
  [9] "Melbourne"                      "Los Angeles, "                         
 [11] "New York, USA"                  "Liverpool, England"            
 [13] "Fort Collins, "                 "London, "                              
 [15] "New York, "
```

The commas I know how to get rid of. As I said, I'm sure this is super simple, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Digits or characters? And by characters <= 2 you mean a word, don't you?

Comment: `gsub(', ..$', '', x)` ? do you want the commas or no

Answer (score 5):

You can use quantifier on a word character `\\w` with word boundaries, `\\b\\w{1,2}\\b` will match a word with one or two characters; use *gsub* to remove it in case you have multiple matched pattern:

```
gsub("\\b\\w{1,2}\\b", "", v)
# [1] "Toronto, "          "Manchester, "       "New York City, "    "Newark, "           "Melbourne"          "Los Angeles, "      "New York, USA"     
# [8] "Liverpool, England" "Fort Collins, "     "London, "           "New York, "
```

Notice `\\w` matches both alpha letters and digits with underscore, if you only want to take alpha letters into account, you can use `gsub("\\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\\b", "", v)`.

---

```
v <- c("Toronto, ON", "Manchester, UK", "New York City, NY", "Newark, NJ", "Melbourne", "Los Angeles, CA", "New York, USA", "Liverpool, England", "Fort Collins, CO", "London, UK", "New York, NY")
```

Comment: Awesome, this works brilliantly. Thanks very much. So simple. I had been playing around with the {1,2} but didn't have the right operators on it beforehand. Out of interest, is there a good resource that lists all the R regex operators? anyway, thanks very much

Comment: You're welcome. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html). It covers the common regex functions in R.

Comment: excellent. thanks very much. bookmarked!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't use regex but it gets the job done:

```
d <- c(
"Toronto, ON",                    "Manchester, UK",                    
"New York City, NY",              "Newark, NJ",             
"Melbourne",                      "Los Angeles, CA"  ,                       
"New York, USA",                  "Liverpool, England" ,           
"Fort Collins, CO",               "London, UK"  ,                            
"New York, NY" )

toks <- strsplit(d, "\\s+")
lens <- sapply(toks, nchar) 

mapply(function(a, b) {
  paste(a[b > 2], collapse = " ")
}, toks, lens)
```

Comment: or  `sapply(strsplit(d, ' '), function(i) paste(i[nchar(i) > 2], collapse = ' '))`